# Can journals decide to refuse previously approved publications conditional to minor revisions?

Tags: publications, journal-workflow

I assisted a professor in writing a paper and it got accepted in a journal with minor reviews. I did the modifications I was asked to address and have been waiting on the professor the rest of the time. I've done friendly reminders once or twice to ask what's going on with the paper but decided to drop the ball as I know they are quite busy. This publication is also obviously more important for me as I don't have anything out there yet, so I'm not so surprised it's probably sitting on a hard drive somewhere. We have a great relationship and there will be opportunities for more publications later on. Still, it was a lot of work for me so I'm keeping my hopes up and the topic can change quickly.

If we do end up submitting the revised paper, can the journal turn it down at a later date on the basis that the delays have been too long? Do journals usually have explicit rules with regards to delays for re-submitting after reviews?

Comment: Usually, journals require revisions to be submitted within a few days. One can ask for an extension, but failing to submit within the deadline usually implies that the submission will be treated as a new one. Do you have the editor's email?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The professor had forwarded it to me so I traced it back and there is no deadline mentioned. However, they do state it could be reviewed quickly when resubmitted and be published in the next issue. That was a LONG time ago.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano That depends strongly on the research area. In math and TCS, it's rather a few weeks (if it's a special issue, where the schedule tends to be more strict). Or a few months. If there is a deadline at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, most journals require revisions to be submitted within a certain time limit as specified in the editors decision letter, typically 3-6 months. Failing that, the paper will be considered withdrawn and any re-submission treated like a new submission. However it is also possible to ask for an extension of the revision deadline, if one can provide good arguments.

Of course, I don't know the details of your case, but you should be able to find out from the journal website.

I also strongly advise you to contact your co-author (preferably in person rather than via email) and enquire about the state of the manuscript and their plans for resubmission.